# simple groups all sylow subgroup is nonabelian

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Thanks for any help or comments

How can I find the list of all non abelian simple groups (particularly simple lie type) such that all $p$-Sylow subgroups are non abelian for odd prime $p$?

Comment: Keep in mind that if a prime $p$ divides the group order just once, a Sylow $p$-subgroup is cyclic.

Comment: @JimHumphreys does such a $p$ always exist?

Comment: Have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109611/cyclic-sylow-p-subgroup-in-finite-simple-groups

Comment: It is a known consequence of the classification of finite simple groups that every finite simple group has a cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup for some prime $p$ dividing the group order (see Geoff's comment), and this prime $p$ can not be $2$ (by Burnside's transfer theorem). (Well, aside from the trivial case $G=C_2$.)

Comment: Note that I asked whether there exists a Sylow subgroup of prime order, which is a bit more than having a (nontrivial) cyclic Sylow subgroup. [Side remarks: (a) the trivial subgroup is a Sylow subgroup! (b) the OP wants only odd prime $p$... so the claim that there exists a nontrivial cyclic Sylow is not enough, if accidentally this is a 2-Sylow and all nontrivial of odd order are nonabelian... which sounds very unlikely, I agree.]

Comment: The question can't be closed as duplicate as long as the other one is not answered... It would be useful to write an answer to the previous one (linked in Geoff's comment)...

Comment: @YCor: A non-Abelian finite simple group never has a cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup. In any finite group with cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup, the elements of odd order form a (normal) subgroup. This can be proved by transfer, or inductively by noting that a generator of a cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ of $G$ acts as an odd permutation in the Cayley permutation representation on $|G|$ points.

Comment: @YCor There should be more interesting things to do on a Friday evening than searching for simple groups with no Sylow subgroups of prime order, but you will hopefully be pleased to learn that the group ${\rm PSU}(3,19)$ has order $16938986400 = 2^53^25^27^319^3$ and ${\rm PSp}(4,7)$ has order $138297600=2^83^25^27^4$. I suppose you might ask whether there are only finitely many such examples. I guess yes.

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks! at least I've seen less worthwhile queries on this site. At this very time, Sloane's EIS doesn't recognize the sequence 138297600,16938986400.

Comment: It may be of more interest to specialists, but it is true that if a finite simple group $G$ has a cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup $P,$ then $P$ is TI in $G$ ( that is, $P \cap P^{g} = 1$ for all $g \in G \backslash N_{G}(P)).$ This is a Theorem of H. Blau ( Proc AMS, 94, (1985)).

Comment: Another pair: $|{\rm PSp}(4,41)| = 6707334818822400 = 2^83^25^27^229^241^4$, and $|{\rm PSp}(4,239)| = 304047481612332847334400=2^{10}3^25^27^213^417^2239^4$.

Comment: @DerekHolt :It's also interesting to see that the order of a finite simple group can be a perfect square ( you seem to have given three examples of this).

Comment: @YCor: The problem with giving an answer to the linked question ( soo that this can be marked as a duplicate) is that the other one is impossible to answer definitively: there is no easy proof at present, but it is impossible to assert that there could never be one.

Comment: @DerekHolt: If a group has only nonabelian Sylow subgroups, every prime factor of its order must occur with multiplicity $\geq 3$, since groups of order $p^2$ are abelian. This holds for none of your examples. Are there finite simple groups with suitable orders (i.e. all prime factors have multiplicity $\geq 3$) at all?

Comment: Those are the only examples that I have found so far. As the groups get larger you get more prime divisors, so it becomes less likely that all exponents will be bigger than $1$. There are no further ${\rm PSp}(4,q)$ examples for $q \le 100000$.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps I will write an answer ( which I will mark as Community Wiki) to highlight some of the issues. From the Classification of Finite Simple Groups it is known that every finite simple group $G$ has at least one cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup ( for an odd prime $p$ which really does divide $|G|$), which is a stronger assertion than required to answer the question. The Alternating Groups are easy to check as noted in comments, and the Sporadic Groups can be checked by easy inspection ( in the Atlas, for example).

Others are better qualified than I am to give a case by case check of the groups of Lie Type, but an analysis of the groups ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$ illustrates both why a positive answer might be expected and why it is not clear that a cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup would necessarily be expected to have prime order ( and Derek Holt's examples of various Symplectic Groups indeed show that this need not be the case).

If we consider $H = {\rm GL}(n,q)$, then $H$ contains a Singer cycle of order $q^{n}-1,$ which gives, in particular, a cyclic subgroup of that order. By Zsigmondy's Theorem, except when $n =2$ or $n =6$ and $q = 2$, there is a prime $r$ which divides $q^{n}-1$ but does not divide $q^{i}-1$ for $ 1 \leq r < n.$
From this it follows ( apart from the exceptional cases) that $H$ has a cyclic Sylow $r$-subgroup and that ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$ has a non-trivial cyclic Sylow $r$-subgroup.

If $n =2$, then any simple ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ has cyclic Sylow $r$-subgroups for any odd prime $r$ which divides $q^{2}-1,$ and there is at least one such prime $r$ as $q >3$ when ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ is simple.

If $n = 6$ and $q = 2,$ then ${\rm GL}(6,2)$ has a cyclic non-trivial Sylow $31$-subgroup ( this is not as ad hoc as it might appear- in general when $n >2$ it can be checked that ${\rm GL}(n,q)$ always has a cyclic Sylow $r$-subgroup for some "Zsigmondy prime divisor" $r$ of one of $q^{n}-1$ or $q^{n-1}-1).$

Notice however, that ( at least without some deeper number theoretic analysis) this "Zsigmondy method" of producing cyclic Sylow $r$-subgroups does not a priori guarantee that $r$ will divide the group order to the first power. For example, ${\rm GL}(5,3)$ has a cyclic Sylow $11$-subgroup of order $11^{2}.$ Looking at ${\rm GL}(4,3)$ shows that ${\rm GL}(5,3)$ does have a cyclic Sylow $5$-subgroup, but in general, I see no obvious reason why all Zsigmondy prime divisors of both $q^{n}-1$ and $q^{n-1}-1$ should not occur to at least the second power.

Later edit: continuing this methodology, or by a direct argument, it is easy to see that for each prime $r$ which divides $|{\rm GL}(n,q)|,$ but not $|{\rm GL}(\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor, q) |,$ the Sylow $r$-subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,q)$ is cyclic, and for large $n$, it would seem very improbable that each such Sylow subgroup had order greater than $r$.