# Maximal order of elements in SL(n,q)

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, matrices, finite-groups, finite-fields

The maximal order of an element of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_q)$ is $q^n-1$, where the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}_q$ is odd $p$.  See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109483/maximal-order-of-elements-in-gln-p) for a nice proof that uses the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem.

However, for $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{F}_q)$ the maximal order is $2p$ if $q=p$ and $q+1$ otherwise.

To see this, note that over $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ any such matrix $A$ is conjugate to an upper-triangular matrix.  If it is not diagonal then its eigenvalues are repeated and $\pm 1$; thus its order is bounded by $2p$. If it is diagonal then the eigenvalues are in $\mathbb{F}_q$ or properly in the degree two extension.  If the former then the order divides $|\mathbb{F}_q^*|=q-1$, and if the latter then $x\mapsto x^q$ generates the Galois group of the extension showing the eigenvalue $a$ satisfies $a^q=a^{-1}\implies a^{q+1}=1 \implies |a|{\large \mid} q+1$.

I did some searching on MO and other places online but did not find a generalization of this for $n\geq 3$.

> Is there a nice formula for the maximal order of an element in $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{F}_q)$?  If so, what is the proof or reference?

**Remark:** I would also be interested in the answer to the same question for other finite groups of Lie type, as well as the even characteristic case.

Comment: For completeness: the maximal order of an element of GL(n,Fq)  is q^n−1 - the cycle generated by that element is called "Singer cycle" - discussed in many papers and at MO e.g. Geoff Robinson here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/254509/10446

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. It is shown in the paper

*Darafsheh, M.R.*, [**Order of elements in the groups related to the general linear group.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ffa.2004.12.003), Finite Fields Appl. 11, No. 4, 738-747 (2005). [ZBL1147.20043](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1147.20043).

(*Theorem 1*)
that the maximal order is 
$$\frac{q^n -1}{q-1},$$ *except* in the case $SL(2, p),$ where the maximum is $2p.$

Comment: Thank you very much Igor.  This question came up yesterday in a meeting with undergraduates in my geometry lab.  After thinking about the SL(2,q) case I optimistically guessed the above formula was the answer and that it was a known fact, but I would never have guessed it was a 2005 Theorem.

Comment: Of course now I wonder, given the relationship between maximal orders in GL, SL, PSL, and PGL, if 1\to H\to G\to Z(G)\to 1 or 1\to Z(G)\to G\to H\to 1 (for a finite group of Lie type G) does the maximal order of an element in H equal the maximal order of an element in G divided by |Z(G)|?  It is probably too good to be true.

Comment: @SeanLawton Just because it was published in 2005 does not mean that it was not known to John Thompson is 1962 :)

Comment: Of course you are right :)  I suppose I was expecting a book on finite groups from that time period as the answer, which is what surprises me.  Thanks again!

Comment: It was probably known to Frobenius or anyone who knew how to study characteristic polynomials (and asked the question).

Comment: @AndreasThom Maybe, but that's no reason to take away credit from the guy who published the 2005 paper.  Who knows how much of what we all published was known before...

Comment: @IgorRivin; that it true.

Comment: @IgorRivin: It is good to have a reference, but I was just thinking that Landau looked at the maximal order of elements in Sym(n) in 1903 because this was a difficult and interesting problem (and the solution relies on the prime number theorem). Those people must have thought about the same problem for linear groups, which is much easier.

Comment: @AndreasThom I completely agree - this is a very natural question.

Comment: Do you folks know of any reference for the maximal order of an element in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})$, where $p$ is a prime?

Comment: Do you know any reference for the list of the order of elements in $GL(2,q)$? There are pieces of literature for the same in the case of symplectic and orthogonal groups though. Please let me know if there are any.